# How to do chalk style drawing with Qt

Tags: qt, drawing

I want to use Qt to draw lines in chalk style, as you typically see on a blackboard. Here is an example of what I have in mind:

[image: Chalk style drawing sample image]

What is the best way to achieve this rendering style? Do I need to draw a lot of little lines with a special brush, or is there a better way to get the "curvy" style you see in the sample image?

And where is the best place to integrate this? Theoretically it would be ideal to get this underneath QPainter, e.g. in a custom QPaintEngine, so that e.g. all the various QPainter::drawLine calls end up using the chalk style. However, it seems while the QPaintEngine interface looks perfect for this, the class itself isn't meant to be used for this purpose...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Greetings,

Fabian

Comment: I would look at creating a textured brush if you want to be able to draw with it. To use a graphics effect would work as an after effect if you had an image that you wanted to add this as a desired effect.

Comment: Yes. I played around with the textured brushes and that might be a way to go. The lines then still look quite "straight" whereas hand-drawn chalk lines are typically more curvy. I am currently experimenting with custom line rendering functions which use splines to make them appear more hand-drawn. Looks promising so far.

Comment: If you get the texture right, it should be able to look right. I did see an article in the past about custom brushes, but can't find it right now. If I come across it again, I'll let you know.

Comment: That article would be nice to have! Btw, I have also managed to get a QPaintEngine proxy running (you need a PaintDevice proxy then as well). This is theoretically a very nice approach since one can modify the behavior at the very low level and use QPainter as is. However, under certain conditions QPainter bypasses the PaintEngine proxy by rendering into an offscreen buffer first (see Qt source: lineEmulation), thus this approach does unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem in a different way. Using textured brushes didn't provide good results (maybe my fault). QGraphicsEffect was unfortunately not an option since my rendering is not based on QGraphicsView.

What I have done in the end:

- Derived an own class from QPainter (i.e. ChalkPainter)
- Added a new drawChalkLine() method to ChalkPainter. This method takes the passed line, splits it into smaller chunks and renders these chunks as bezier curves via QPainter::drawPath. For each bezier curve chunk I randomly shift the control point orthogonal to the line.
- Next I added additional rendering methods to the ChalkPainter class, such as drawChalkRect(), all internally using the drawChalkLine() method.

This is not the most elegant method since I can't use the QPainter methods directly, but it provides good results for my purpose. Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking in QGraphicsEffect's way.. I think it should be possible to develop such a filter which will produce similar effect..

I'll update in here answer on your comment.

No, QGraphicsEffect can be applied 'per graphics item'. If you have a look on QGraphicsItem you will see that there is a setGraphicsEffect method, so you can design an effect which works on QGraphicsLineItem for example and set it only on lines you want to look chalky..

Important thing is that you don't have to operate on pre-drawn image, you can either make it completely owner-draw item with graphicsEffect (for example make an assumption that effect is only applicable on QGraphicsLineItem) pre-draw it using drawSource() and then modify OR draw it completely from scratch..

I would love to help you with some coding, probably will do it somewhere around next week, since I will need similar thing for project I am working on now.. but physically don't have time next few days..

I'll update an answer with sources link as soon as it's done.

Custom brush also looks really promising..

Comment: True, that's one way of solving this. However, the graphics effect works on the final image data, right? Thus the algorithm would have to detect the lines in the image in order to modify them; sounds quite tricky.